# How to add Alt images using Wix

Tags: seo, images, alt-attribute

There is no option to do this in the media library. I am using an image gallery, and under settings they provide field inputs for "Title" and "Description". According to their knowledge base, the "Description" is the "Alt text". First of all those are two different things and its frustrating that they mix terms, and second of all the Alt tag is still empty in chrome dev tools.

How do I properly add the Alt text to images used in a gallery in Wix so that I can actually verify Google can read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is also used as alt.
Note that both gallery image title and gallery image description are part of the image's schema (http://schema.org/ImageObject) which tells Google they are describing the image and are, at least, powerful as the alt text.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with my alt tags showing up blank in chrome dev tools. I don't have any confirmation that it's actually displaying the way it's currently set.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Alt text to the images on your site provides users and search engines with information about your images and helps search engines "read" them.
To add Alt Text to an image:

1) Click the image.
2) Click the Settings icon ﻿
﻿
3) Enter a description of the image under What's in the image? Tell Google.

Note: This description provides visitors and search engines (such as Google) with information about your image.

Comment: This is copy and pasted from the knowledge base. As I said it isn't showing up in chrome dev tools

Answer (score 0):

To add Alt Text to an image:

Click the image.
Click the Settings icon. 
Enter a description of the image under "What's in the image?"
More via: https://www.wix.com/support/html5/article/images-and-seo

Comment: https://d2x3xhvgiqkx42.cloudfront.net/12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab/2016/04/27/bec668bd-03a4-4004-b799-25c493204060.png may be interesting too